# Vending Machine Program help(python)

Tags: python

I'm kinda stuck on something. Well, alot of things but one step at a time right. I'm not sure how to get the program to add the choices that the user input together. The assignment asks me to make a vending machine that gets a users input, return the total to them when they input 0 to quit, then it will ask them to enter the money to pay, if it is a valid amount, it will dispense change, if not, it will ask for more money. Right now though, I'm stuck on it returning the user choices and adding the total together. I will paste my code below. thanks

```
def main():
    userchoice = ()
    while userchoice != 0:

        # First, the vending machine will display a message on its "screen"
        print("Welcome to the Vending Machine!")

        # Now, the vending machine will display the available items
        Options()

        # Now, the first input will ask the user to enter their choice
        userchoice = float(input("Please enter the number corresponding to your preferred item or 0 to quit: "))

        # Now, the program will print the choice and re-run it until the user selects 0

        choices = []
        choices.append(userchoice)

        if userchoice == 1:
            print("You selected one can of Dr.Pepper for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 2:
            print("You selected one can of Mtn.Dew for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 3:
            print("You selected one bottle of Water for $1.00")

        elif userchoice == 4:
            print("You selected one bag of Doritos for $1.75")

        elif userchoice == 5:
            print("You selected one Snickers bar for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 6:
            print("You selected one pack of Gum for $0.50")

        elif userchoice == 0:
            print(choices)

        else:
            print("Invalid Choice, Please Try Again")


def Options():
    print("\t1. Dr.Pepper - $1.50\n"
          "\t2. Mtn.Dew - $1.50\n"
          "\t3. Water - $1.00\n"
          "\t4. Doritos - $1.75\n"
          "\t5. Snickers - $1.50\n"
          "\t6. Gum - $0.50")


def Sum(userchoice):
    return userchoice + userchoice


main()
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to get the program to add the choices that the user input together." Well, where did you put all those choices? (Hint: when you write `choices.append(userchoice)`, what is the *intended purpose* of that?) What kind of thing is that? (Hint: when you write `choices = []`, what does that mean?) Can that thing contain numbers? (Yes.) Does it? (Hint: where does `userchoice` get its value?) Do you know how to add up such numbers? (Hint: *review your course notes*.)

Comment: That still won't get you to a working solution, because there are other errors in your program. To address these, you should try to learn some [debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and also try to think carefully about the intended logic of the program. For example, how many times should `choices = []` happen? Therefore, should that be inside a loop, or outside?

Comment: You should also try to use functions to *do less work at a time*. For example, try writing a function that simply asks the user for *one* vending machine selection, and `return`s the selected value. Then try to make the rest of the code *use* that function.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered one problem which is that when you declare `choices` you declare it inside the loop, meaning it becomes `[]` each time the user picks something.
Try this:

```py
def main():
    choices = []
    userchoice = ()
    while userchoice != 0:

        # First, the vending machine will display a message on its "screen"
        print("Welcome to the Vending Machine!")

        # Now, the vending machine will display the available items
        Options()

        # Now, the first input will ask the user to enter their choice
        userchoice = int(input("Please enter the number corresponding to your preferred item or 0 to quit: "))

        # Now, the program will print the choice and re-run it until the user selects 0

        
        choices.append(userchoice)

        if userchoice == 1:
            print("You selected one can of Dr.Pepper for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 2:
            print("You selected one can of Mtn.Dew for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 3:
            print("You selected one bottle of Water for $1.00")

        elif userchoice == 4:
            print("You selected one bag of Doritos for $1.75")

        elif userchoice == 5:
            print("You selected one Snickers bar for $1.50")

        elif userchoice == 6:
            print("You selected one pack of Gum for $0.50")

        elif userchoice == 0:
            print(choices)

        else:
            print("Invalid Choice, Please Try Again")


def Options():
    print("\t1. Dr.Pepper - $1.50\n"
          "\t2. Mtn.Dew - $1.50\n"
          "\t3. Water - $1.00\n"
          "\t4. Doritos - $1.75\n"
          "\t5. Snickers - $1.50\n"
          "\t6. Gum - $0.50")


def Sum(userchoice):
    return userchoice + userchoice


main()
```

This means that the `choices` variable now has something useful in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more refined approach, it always helps to see different design concepts:

```
options = {
    '1': {'title':'Dr.Pepper','price':1.50},
    '2': {'title':'Mtn.Dew','price':1.50},
    '3': {'title':'Water','price':1.00},
    '4': {'title':'Doritos','price':1.75},
    '5': {'title':'Snickers','price':1.50},
    '6': {'title':'Gum','price':0.50}
}

def get_number(question):
    value = input(question)
    while 1:
        try:
            value = int(value)
            break
        except:
            value = input(f'(must be a number) {question}')
    return value

def main():
    choices = []
    amount = 0
    while 1:

        # First, the vending machine will display a message on its "screen"
        print("Welcome to the Vending Machine!")

        # Now, the vending machine will display the available items
        for k, v in options.items():
            print(f"\t{k}. {v['title']} - ${v['price']:.2f}")

        # Now, the first input will ask the user to enter their choice
        userchoice = get_number('Please enter the number corresponding to your preferred item or 0 to quit:')
        if userchoice == 0:
            break
        # Now, the program will print the choice and re-run it until the user selects 0
        choice = options.get(str(userchoice), None)
        if choice:
            choices.append(choice['title'])
            amount += choice['price']
            print(f"You selected one {choice['title']} for ${choice['price']:.2f}")
        else:
            print('Invalid Choice, Please Try Again')

    print('Your Cart Contains:')
    for each in sorted(choices):
        print(each)
    print(f'Total Amount: {amount}')
    return choices, amount

choices, amount = main()
```